# Unable to solve '-' is a bad directive in format '%-m/%-d/%Y %-H:%M'

Tags: python, pandas

My code:

```
crime = pd.read_csv("DATA/OAKLAND.csv", parse_dates=True)
time_format = '%-m/%-d/%Y %H:%M'
crime['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(crime['DATETIME'], format=time_format)
```

Error that occurs:

```
'-' is a bad directive in format '%-m/%-d/%Y %H:%M'
```

Some sample dates:

```
10/10/2018 20:00
11/19/2018 14:15
12/10/2018 18:51
10/29/2018 7:30
10/7/2018 14:30
1/2/2019 0:01
```

Does anyone know what the right time_format is?  So far I am unable to get the correct code..
Thanks

Comment: does your time look like they have dashes in them?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what you are asking for. But if I add the code errors='coerce', then dates are printed. Can I conclude from this that there are some errors in the dataset that caused the error to pop up?

Answer (score 0):

When having this error, you know you won't use '-' as a directive format.
Thus you should adopt for instance an alternative strategy by replacing the '-' character before translating formatting into datetime :

1/ first way of replacing for instance

```py
from datetime import datetime
from re import sub

date = '2021-07-02 00:00:00'

# re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
cdat = datetime.strptime(sub('-', '', date), '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')

print(cdat)
# 2021-07-02 00:00:00
```

2/ second way of replacing for instance

```py
# re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
cdat = datetime.strptime(date.replace('-', ''), '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
print(cdat)
# 2021-07-02 00:00:00
```

This is just for datetime converting, but here is an example with a pandas  dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd
crime = pd.DataFrame({"DATETIME": ['10-10-2018 20:00', '11-19-2018 14:15']})

#            DATETIME
# 0  10-10-2018 20:00
# 1  11-19-2018 14:15

crime = crime.applymap(lambda x: sub('-', '', str(x)))
#         DATETIME
# 0  10102018 20:00
# 1  11192018 14:15


time_format = '%m%d%Y %H:%M'
crime['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(crime['DATETIME'], format=time_format)

print(crime)
#             DATETIME
# 0 2018-10-10 20:00:00
# 1 2018-11-19 14:15:00
```